# Code review tool for GitHub

Tags: code-review, github

We're now a pretty big development team (40+ developers) and we have a multitude of projects, spread across many GitHub repositories. So far we've been using GitHub's pull-requests to do code reviews, but as you can imagine keeping track of what's been reviewed, what hasn't, what needs fixing and what has been fixed is getting harder.

We would like to use some tool, that works on top of GitHub's pull requests. I imagine it would be some kind of dashboard that gives answers to the following questions.

- Which pull requests do I need to review and approve.
- Who am I waiting for to review my own pull requests.
- Has the comment I've left earlier been addressed.
- What has changed since my last review.
- *It should work across multiple GitHub repositories*
- *It should integrate with GitHub's pull requests, rather than try to absorb everything*

We've evaluated already:

- https://reviewable.io/
- https://www.gerritcodereview.com/
- https://www.gitcolony.com/
- https://www.review.ninja/

but none of them fit the criteria above (review.ninja seems the most promising but it lacks a high-level dashboard for all projects, for example).

Comment: Ditch Github and use Phabricator. You can host it yourself or get it remotely hosted. https://secure.phabricator.com/